# My scrollview is not working in react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, scrollview

im making scroll component visible when someone pressed on input

[image]

this is my itemfinder.js link https://drive.google.com/file/d/182ZQf7Ocx7hiJVfaJJjv_pvP32bL3kaN/view?usp=share_link

this is my file which i called itemfinder component https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dAQPk3Hw9vJ7CM3zbzGpCgDDw_LeGB54/view?usp=share_link

i want to make it scroll
im new to react native
anad im using expo for this

Thank you

Comment: so what is your current issue?  scrollview is not working with input?

Comment: so when you tap on input then you want to show or scroll scrollview, right?

Comment: @JatinBhuva yes im using scroll view for first time too

Comment: would be better if you write the code instead of the image, easier for others to copy and run on their end to find the solution.

Comment: @JatinBhuva idk is it really dont work with input i will see is it work normally without input now

Comment: i tried with your styling, and its working for me fine, kindly edit your post and share the code of `<ItemView />`

Comment: @PakDragoon bro i swear im new to stackoverflow i dont know how when i copy the code it not formatting code nicely

Comment: just type your code as you do in vscode, and write ``` before first line and ``` after last line.

Comment: @PakDragoon it giving error It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: yes you need to explain a little bit about what are you doing in your code as a description. code will be in between ``` and description will be outside.

Comment: @PakDragoon https://drive.google.com/file/d/182ZQf7Ocx7hiJVfaJJjv_pvP32bL3kaN/view?usp=share_link     my file downloadlink pls helpme

Comment: tried it, it is working fine for me. you are currently unable to scroll up/down right? kindly show where actually you are rendering your `RenderView` component?

Comment: @PakDragoon im so sry for late reply my bad

Comment: @PakDragoon link for that file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dAQPk3Hw9vJ7CM3zbzGpCgDDw_LeGB54/view?usp=share_link

Comment: @minnu are you fixed?

Comment: @Ajith no bro im still not fixed pls help me

Comment: if you want to scroll, you must be wrapped by <View>
ex : <View style={{width,height}}><ScrollView>....</ScrollView></View>

Comment: @Ajith what do i do now my problem is not in renderView component it is in itemView component

Comment: @Ajith the link for the whole file https://drive.google.com/file/d/182ZQf7Ocx7hiJVfaJJjv_pvP32bL3kaN/view?usp=share_link    pls help mee

Comment: didn't understand your issue

Comment: @Ajith bro when i putting normal text element instead of my owncreated element the scrollview is working the problem is in itemview component click the link for full code bro

Comment: change RenderView component Scrollview {height='45%'} to {minHight:'30%',maxHeight:'60%'}